MCAddon file creation
I am making a Bedrock Edition add-on. I have 2 folders, one for a custom item and another for a custom weapon/tool. Both have a behavior and resource pack associated with them. Do I have to convert those to mcpack files and the same for the 2 outer-most folders (converting them to mcaddon files)?
The structure that I have is this:
Addon-->the two folders with custom items and equipment(will add more)--> behavior and resource pack for the items
 Sorry if this is an oversimiplication as I don't know how to make those fancy trees.

Um, yes? It's just a glorified zip file. Also, could you share your folder structure?

Addon->1->behavior and resource
->2->behavior and resource
Sorry for the bad format (not sure how to get new lines) on the comments

you'll have to edit it back into the question; there's no new lines for comments.


Do I have to convert those to .mcpack and .mcaddon files?

It's not entirely clear from your question exactly what you are trying to do, but .mcaddon files should only contain .mcpack files. Please comment if that was indeed what you were asking.
Here is the correct file structure for a .mcaddon file.
My Example Addon.mcaddon
|
|-> My Resource Pack.mcpack
|
|-> My Behavior Pack.mcpack

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/documents/minecraftfileextensions

There is another method where the resource and behavior packs are both just regular folders - not even zipped. Drag and drop both BP and RP to your desktop, directly adjacent to each other. Left click the screen and drag to select both folders, then right click on one of the selected items, and from the popup menu select "Compress to..." -> "ZIP file." The zip will then contain both RP and BP folders. Then, select the zip file's name, and change the extension from ".zip" to ".mcaddon." The icon will change to the Minecraft grass block logo and double clicking will import it into the game.

Demo here: https://youtu.be/glMozhQQ2hs?si=cdlAzoJmUxgIwiio&t=105

I just tested your method and it seems to work the exact same way, so it only depends on whether or not you've already converted the RP and BP from folders to .mcpacks, which method would be more convenient to use. +1 :)
